# Reduce date values to reveal only 2 characters within the year (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to reduce a date column to reveal the YY vs YYYY

**Data**

```
ID      Date    Stat
AA11    Q1.2022 y
BB11    Q1.2022 y
BB11    Q1.2022 n
```

**Desired**

```
 ID     Date    Stat
 AA11   Q1.22   y
 BB11   Q1.22   y
 BB11   Q1.22   n
```

**Doing**

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(datetime).datetime[:-2]
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: str(x[0:3])+str(x[-2:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `apply`, better use a regex here:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\.\d{2}', '.')
```

Or, if Date is already a string:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str[:3]+df['Date'].str[-2:]
```

Comment: @MohammadMufassirKhan this is the opposite, `apply` is generally slower (non vectorized)